# How to use C++ regex with this condition?

Tags: c++, regex

I have the following C++ code:

```
std::regex e("'[^\"]'");
std::smatch sm;
std::regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), sm, e);
std::cout << sm.str() << " match\n";
```

I tried to create a condition which should basically accept all the strings that begin and end with one apostrophes (`''`), and between them there is must to be everything that is double quote (`"`).

EDIT:
For example, that sample doesn't works (and it should):

```
std::string s("'example'");
```

Comment: Can you provide some samples of expected matches please? Your regex looks completely off regarding your prose.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ of course! i maked edits. thanks

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wish it would. My example should be matches but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the regex. You want to match any number of non `"` character occurrence. The `any number of` (`*`) regex operator fixes this:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string s("'example'");
    std::regex e("'[^\"]*'");
                     // ^ Allow any characters besides "
    std::smatch sm;
    std::regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), sm, e);
    std::cout << sm.str() << " match\n";
    return 0 ;
}
```

See the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbfd9941dd6138e5).